# Limit of exponential function (Eulers number)

Tags: calculus, limits, euler-mascheroni-constant

I'm struggling with this assignment for a couple of hours, and i dont seem to find any clues :(

I have to find the limit of this exponential function:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n+2})^{2n+3} $$

I've already tried to rewrite the expression as:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} ((1+\frac{1}{n+2})^{n+2})^{\frac{2n+3}{n+2}}$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n+3}{n+2} = 2 $$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n+2})^{2n+4}$$
$$k=n+2$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{k})^{2k})$$

But it didn't help actually. I know i have to rewrite the limit to the form of:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^{n}= e^x$$
Unfortunately i'm out of ideas now. I will really appreciate any tips from you guys. I totally stuck with this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have solved the problem yourself. Just check this.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n+2})^{2n+3} $$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^{n+2}\right)^{\frac{2n+3}{n+2}}$$
$$= \left(\lim_{(n+2) \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^{n+2}\right)^{\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2n+3}{n+2}}$$
$$=e^{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n+3}{n+2}} =e^2 $$

Comment: Where is the fault in my reasoning?

We have: $2n+3=(n+2)+(n+1)$. So
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n+2})^{2n+3}=\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left( \underbrace{(1+\frac{1}{n+2})^{n+2}}_\text{$\to e$ as  $n \to +\infty$}\cdot (1+\frac{1}{n+2})^{n+1}\right)$$

i.e. if the limit equals $e^2$, then $\lim_{n \to +\infty} (1+\frac{1}{n+2})^{n+1}$ should go to $e$, but it clearly does not.

Comment: @derthomas It truly goes to $e$. $\large\frac{\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n+2})^{(n+2)}}{\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n+2})}=\frac{e}{1}$

Comment: Oh yes, I see. The source of my faulty reasoning was in thinking that

$$\left(\left(\lim_{n\to+\infty}f(x)=e\right) \wedge \left(\lim_{n\to+\infty}g(x)=e\right)\right) \implies f(x)=g(x)$$

which is complete non sense

Comment: @derthomas You're welcome.